# SQL server : I need to add 2 numbers in any combinations (Even more than once). The sum should exceed a 3rd number but should be the closest

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations

Below is a row from the table i have in SQL server.

```
Drug Unit Vial1 Vial2 Vial3
  X    55    50    12
```

--**--

```
Drug = X
Unit = 55
Vial1 = 50
Vial2 = 12
Vial3 = Null
```

A doctor injected 55 units(Column unit) of drug X to a patient. 
He can choose 2 x Vial1 = 100, which means he can use 55 for injection and discard 45(Cant store the opened vial for future use).

Or he can use 5 x Vial2 = 60, which means he can use 55 for injection and discard 5.

Or he can use 1 x Vial1 + 1 x Vial2 = 62, which means he can use 55 for injection and discard 7.

Similarly he can use any combinations (say 2 x Vial2 + 1 x vial1).

What i need to find is which combination is the closest to Unit (Combination should equal or exceed the unit). In this case it is 5 x vial2.

I need a SQL code to figure this out. Sorry, i couldnt come up with any idea.

Thank you all!

Regards,
Thamizhamudhan.R

Comment: This type of optimization problem is not ideal for SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Is it possible to write programatically with T SQL?  I am new to the technical world. Please bear with my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with t as (
      select 'X' as drug, 55 as unit, 50 as vial1, 12 as vial2
     ),
     cte as (
      select drug, unit, vial1, vial2, 0 as num1, 0 as num2, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select drug, unit, vial1, vial2, num1 + 1, num2, lev + 1
      from cte
      where num1 * vial1 + num2 * vial2 < unit
      union all 
      select drug, unit, vial1, vial2, num1 , num2 + 1, lev + 1
      from cte
      where num1 * vial1 + num2 * vial2 < unit
     )
select top (1) cte.*
from cte
where num1 * vial1 + num2 * vial2 >= unit
order by num1 * vial1 + num2 * vial2 - unit;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7950b9f38f8048ec3ea178262b2f09b8) is a db<>fiddle.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=423202c08f12cca1b3948afa3afb1e1d) is another example with all three vials.

Comment: Thank you very much!! You saved my day.

Comment: Just now noticed the 3 vial example. Its so thoughtful of you to provide me with it. Appreciate your help.